# Configuring SSL client certificate in android app for client authentication in web server on tomcat

Tags: android, apache, tomcat, ssl, client-server

I installed apache server locally on my computer and running . I started with SSL server certificate for server authentication.  To do this i added the server keystore path to the server.xml file of the tomcat and server certificate to truststore of SSL context in android app.Its working perfectly fine.

Now I need to configure the same for client authentication. For that I created a client keystore and stored that keystore in the resources/raw folder of android app and put that in keystore of the android app.

I created keystore for server and client using the below commands .

```
keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keystore server.jks
keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -keystore client.jks
keytool -export -file server.cert -keystore server.jks -storepass password -alias server
keytool -export -file client.cert -keystore client.jks -storepass password -alias client
```

So i created 2 keystores , one for client and other for server , client.jks and server.jks . And i have client.cer and server.cer certificates exported from the corresponding keystore.

Client (Android application code) used to configure the SSL context . I have stored client.jks and server.cer files in the res/raw folder and referring that in the below code.

```
public HttpClient myHttpsClient() {
    HttpClient client = null;
    char[] passphrase = "password".toCharArray();

    try {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        CertificateFactory clientcf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.server);
        InputStream clientcert = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client);
        Certificate ca;
        Certificate clientca;
        try {
            clientca = clientcf.generateCertificate(clientcert);
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            System.out.println("ca="+ ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
            clientcert.close();
        }
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStoreclient = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStoreclient.load(null, null);
        keyStoreclient.setCertificateEntry("ca", clientca);


        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);



        String kmfAlgorithm = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(kmfAlgorithm);
            kmf.init(keyStoreclient,passphrase);



        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        MySSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(context);//,new BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier());

        client = createHttps(socketFactory);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return client;
```

Now the server is configured as below .

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" truststoreFile="/Users/prabhuraj/client.cer" 
truststorePass="password" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
port="8443" keystoreFile="/Users/prabhuraj/server.jks" keystorePass="password"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

After configuring as above. SSL handshake is failing . Can someone please let me know whether i am configuring wrongly?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt use your `KeyManagerFactory` to init `SSLContext`,

change:

`context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);`

to

`context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);`

However, your certificate used for client auth, will need it's private key. Look at this post for explaination: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11199270/2762154

Comment: Thanks Than for the reply. I did change the null to kmf.getKeyManagers() , still no luck with that .

Comment: Hi Than , quick query on your comment abt private key . When I created a keystore using key tool i.e. server.jks and client.jks , it will have a certificate , private key pair in it . So I extracted the certificate out of the keystore i.e. client.cer and server.cer . And now I added client.cer to the truststore of the server and server.jks to the keystore of the server. Similarly server.cer to the truststore of the client and client.jks to the keystore of the client. So both communicating parties has their private keys for the certificate which they are presenting. IS anything wrong in this ?

Comment: Change your keystore to .BKS, android doesn't support JKs keystores. Extracted certificate has public key only.

Comment: Thank you Than. It worked for me. But still I am not very clear with the procedure I used. keystore will store a private key and certificate(public key). I created a key store in BKS format and configured that in android app (client)key store. And I converted that BKS keystore into jKS using portecle and that I configured in the truststore of the server . So both the communicating parties hv both private key and public key. Is it the right way? I believe for client authentication  client should hv a private key and public key and server should only have its public key. Could u please clarify?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Usage-of-Digital-Certificate.svg